# Jquery form validator not working properly in Google Apps Script

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-caja

I am using [***this Jquery form validation plugin***](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) in my GAS project along with HTMLServices. While the ***valid()*** method of the plugin works perfectly well, the ***validate()*** function is not working properly & does not even seem to trigger. I am completely out of clues with this. Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript in GAS is run through a Caja sanitizer before it is allowed to execute. So, test your code in the [Caja playground](http://caja.appspot.com) and see if the validate() method is blocked by Caja.

Comment: I am quite new to GAS and CAJA. The help link in CAJA playground too does not work. Could you point me towards some resources that would help me understand how to work with the CAJA Playground.